# How can I get the all images which are stored in NSDocumentsDirectory in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

How can I retrieve all the images from `NSDocumentsDirectory`? I don't know the image name but I need to store all the images in `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you loop thru all the files in the document directory and check whether there extension is that of an image? Because your question as it is now looks like a code request which is frowned upon and might get you downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming you mean the Documents Directory specific to your app sandbox. If so you can access that directory using `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];`

Cycle through that directory and look for files that have a .png or .jpg e.t.c. path extension.

i.e:

```
NSString *string = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:string];
for (NSString *doc in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", doc);
    if ([doc.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
    // Is jpg image obviously you want to search for different formats also
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude

```
-(NSMutableArray*)pullOutAllImagesInDocumentsDirectory{

    NSArray *listOfPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [listOfPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *imageFilePathsCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int imageIndex=0; imageIndex<filePathsArray.count; imageIndex++) {

        NSString *strFilePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]||
            [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"]||
            [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {

            [imageFilePathsCollection addObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];

        }
    }

    return imageFilePathsCollection;

}
```

**NOTE: it will give image url path. in order to get the image, you can use**

```
[yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:"Path Of Image"]];
```